# C++ - Syntax error when using a reference in constructor

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, syntax-error

I'm developing a small OOP/RAII library that wraps Win32's `mixerXXX` API functions.

I'm writing a class that encapsulates the `MIXERLINE` structure, so my `MixerLine` class has this as its header:

```
#pragma once
#define UNICODE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
#include "MixerDevice.h"

//////////////////////////////

class MixerLine {

private:
    MIXERLINE _mixerLine;

public:

    MixerLine(MixerDevice& parentMixer, DWORD destinationIndex); 

    ~MixerLine();

};
```

However I get a syntax error (in VC9):

> Error 2   error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'MixerDevice'    d:\tfs\misc\winwavein\mixerline.h

Why isn't the message more helpful? I have no idea what's wrong with it.

FWIW, there are no errors at all in the file `MixerDevice.h`.

EDIT: Here are the original, entire files:

MixerLine.h

```
#pragma once

#define UNICODE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>

#include <windows.h>

#include "MixerDevice.h"

//////////////////////////////

class MixerLine {

private:
    MIXERLINE _mixerLine;

public:

    MixerLine(MixerDevice& parentMixer, DWORD destinationIndex); 

    ~MixerLine();

    // Properties

    DWORD getDestinationLineIndex() {
        return _mixerLine.dwDestination;
    }   

    DWORD getSourceIndex() {
        return _mixerLine.dwSource;
    }

    DWORD getLineId() {
        return _mixerLine.dwLineID;
    }

    DWORD getStatus() {
        return _mixerLine.fdwLine;
    }

    std:wstring getStatusString() {

        switch( _mixerLine.fdwLine ) {
            case MIXERLINE_LINEF_ACTIVE:
                return L"MIXERLINE_LINEF_ACTIVE";
            case MIXERLINE_LINEF_DISCONNECTED:
                return L"MIXERLINE_LINEF_DISCONNECTED";
            case MIXERLINE_LINEF_SOURCE:
                return L"MIXERLINE_LINEF_SOURCE";
            default:
                return L"";
        }

    }

    DWORD getUserData() {
        return _mixerLine.dwUser;
    }

    DWORD getComponentType() {
        return _mixerLine.dwComponentType;
    }
};
```

MixerDevice.h

```
#pragma once
#define UNICODE

#include <memory>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include <windows.h>

////////////////////////

#include "MixerLine.h"

class MixerDevice {

    private:
        DWORD     _deviceId;
        HMIXER    _mixerHandle;
        MIXERCAPS _mixerCaps;

    public:
        MixerDevice(DWORD deviceId);
        ~MixerDevice();

        void enumerateLines();

        // Properties

        DWORD getDeviceId() {
            return _deviceId;
        }

        HMIXEROBJ getHandle() {
            return (HMIXEROBJ)_mixerHandle;
        }

        // Caps

        WORD getManufacturerId() {
            return _mixerCaps.wMid;
        }
        WORD getProductId() {
            return _mixerCaps.wPid;
        }
        MMVERSION getDriverVersion() {
            return _mixerCaps.vDriverVersion;
        }
        WCHAR* getProductName() {
            return _mixerCaps.szPname;
        }
        DWORD getSupportBits() {
            return _mixerCaps.fdwSupport;
        }
        DWORD getDestinationCount() {
            return _mixerCaps.cDestinations;
        }
    };
```

MixerDevice.cpp (the file I'm trying to compile):

```
#include "MixerDevice.h"

using namespace std;

MixerDevice::MixerDevice(DWORD deviceId) {

    _deviceId = deviceId;

    MMRESULT result;

    result = mixerOpen( &_mixerHandle, deviceId, NULL, NULL, MIXER_OBJECTF_MIXER );
    if( result != MMSYSERR_NOERROR ) throw new exception("Call to mixerOpen failed.", result);

    result = mixerGetDevCaps( (UINT)_mixerHandle, &_mixerCaps, sizeof(MIXERCAPS) );
    if( result != MMSYSERR_NOERROR ) throw new exception("Call to mixerGetDevCaps failed.", result);
}

MixerDevice::~MixerDevice() {

    MMRESULT result = mixerClose( _mixerHandle );
    if( result != MMSYSERR_NOERROR ) exit(666);
}

// Methods

void MixerDevice::enumerateLines() {    
}
```

Comment: Missing semi-colon? There is a missing semi-colon at the end of `MixerLine`, possibly same mistake at end of `MixerDevice`?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add that to my Question. The semicolon is present in MixerLine.h

Comment: @David: When posting a question about a syntax error, you **must** post your exact code.  Otherwise we could all end up wasting our time...

Comment: Can you post `MixerDevice.h`.

Comment: Maybe there is a macro definition for MixerDevice somewhere in the headers?

Comment: You have another syntax error in `MixerLine.h`: `std:wstring` -- a colon is missing (`std::wstring`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Luchian Grigore already stated, a forward-declaration is better if it's sufficient than including the whole header (at least, here, and IMHO).

`#pragma once` does not help with circular inclusions, it only avoids infinite inclusions._

But the inclusion starts within `MixerDevice.cpp`:

MixerDevice.cpp --`#include`--> MixerDevice.h --`#include`--> MixerLine.h --`#include`-->MixerDevice.h

That last `#include` directive does nothing because of the `#pragma once` in `MixerDevice.h`. The preprocessor assembles a single document (translation unit) that looks like (use `/P` or `/showIncludes` to see that):

1. contents of several StdLib and windows headers
2. contents of MixerLine.h
3. contents of MixerDevice.h
4. contents of MixerDevice.cpp

This is what the compiler receives as input, effectively. Now, when the compiler reaches the line within the contents of `MixerLine.h`:

```
MixerLine(MixerDevice& parentMixer, DWORD destinationIndex);
```

The name `MixerDevice` is not known yet; that name is introduced "below" in the document within the contents of `MixerDevice.h`. You need at least declare the class `MixerDevice` before using its name. You could also change your inclusion order as `MixerDevice` currently does not depend on `MixerLine`, but *you'll probably run into more trouble later this way*.

After some discussion with Luchian Grigore I want to point out:

**Don't solve the problem by reversing the inclusion order, this solution is something that works ONLY in this particular case and ONLY if you mention no name in `MixerDevice.h` that is only declared in `MixerLine.h`. Use forward-declarations instead, as mentioned by Luchian Grigore.**

Comment: The problem **is** circular inclusion, that doesn't mean infinite inclusion. It means that the contents of the headers aren't expanded because the include guards aren't bypassed. You clearly don't know what the underlying problem with circular includes is if you think `pragma once` or include guards makes it ok...

Comment: That's one way to see it. I wanted to stress out where the error message comes from, that is, the name is not known. You can well have circular inclusion that works well (here) by reversing the inclusion order, that's why I've written that it's not the problem. I didn't want to deny circular inclusion in most cases is bad style and leads to problems.

Comment: The problem wouldn't be solved if you reverse the order. At best, a different one would appear. When the contents are pasted by the pre-processor, all after the other include is excluded. So neither of the symbols is known.

Comment: _This particular problem_ can be solved by including `MixerLine.h` in `MixerDevice.cpp` instead of `MixerDevice.h`, I just tried it out to double-check. With only _this_ code provided here, it works, as the whole `MixerDevice.h` file is not dependent on `MixerLine.h` (does not mention the name `MixerLine`).

Comment: Agreed. But doing that you remove the circular include. You're saying the circular inclusion is *not* the problem, but you can't seem to solve it without removing the circular include. So how is it not the problem?

Comment: I don't see where I'm removing the circular inclusion: `MixerLine.h` still includes `MixerDevice.h` and vice versa (with `#pragma once` avoiding the inclusion effectively).

Comment: Including one in the header first is a workaround and doesn't solve the essential issue. You will have to do the same **for all files** that include one or the other. You're basically patching things up but leaving the problem still there.

Comment: I thought I had stressed out that enough in my answer, but you showed my this was not the case. Edited my answer.

Comment: Ok, great. +1 It's good that you explained the source, but in general you should look for solutions that solve the underlying issue, not only a particular case.

Answer (score 2):

You have circular includes in your code, no wonder it doesn't work. You'll need to replace includes with forward-declarations where possible in the headers.

**MixerLine.h** - replace include with forward declaration:

```
//#include "MixerDevice.h"
class MixerDevice;
```

and move the implementation to implementation files.